# Add Small Image Size to Media Settings

Tags: images, media-settings

My WordPress (v4.7) site's media settings only shows sizes for Thumbnail, Medium, and Large.  How do I add a Small size to it?

Answer (score 1):

You can register a new image size by using **[`add_image_size()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/)**

> `add_image_size( string $name, int $width, int $height, bool|array $crop = false )`
>
> ### Parameters
>
> **$name**
>
> (string) (Required) Image size identifier.
>
> **$width**
>
> (int) (Required) Image width in pixels. $height (int) (Required) Image
> height in pixels.
>
> **$crop**
>
> (bool|array) (Optional) Whether to crop images
> to specified width and height or resize. An array can specify
> positioning of the crop area. Default value: false

Answer (score 1):

Before modifying themes you should create a child theme of you theme

https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

you can then add one of the following options to you `functions.php` in the child theme

`add_image_size( 'custom-size', 220, 180 );`

reference this page for croping and resizing options
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

To use add image In a theme’s functions.php file. Always use the “after_setup_theme” action hook.

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'wpdocs_theme_setup' );
function wpdocs_theme_setup() {
    add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300 ); // 300 pixels wide (and unlimited height)
    add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); // (cropped)
}
```

Or you can also use the `set_post_thumbnail_size` function with some of the options listed below

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );`
`set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 );`
Note
This function will not resize your existing featured images. To regenerate existing images in the new size, use the Regenerate Thumbnails plugin.

Crop Mode
Set the default Post Thumbnail size by resizing the image proportionally (that is, without distorting it):

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50 ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, resize mode`

Set the default Post Thumbnail size by cropping the image (either from the sides, or from the top and bottom):

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, true ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, crop mode`

Set the default Post Thumbnail size by cropping the image from top left:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, array( 'left', 'top')  ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, crop from the top left corner`

Set the default Post Thumbnail size by cropping the image from the center:

`set_post_thumbnail_size( 50, 50, array( 'center', 'center')  ); // 50 pixels wide by 50 pixels tall, crop from the center`